# CSS3 Scale combined with reflect makes blurred elements on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, scale, blur

There is a kind of weird bug on chrome when you try to combine css3 scale and css3 reflect on a div with content.

I would like to know if someone know a fix or hack to get a sharp result.

*The content of my div can be text, video, image, svg... and can contain animation

I made the following codepen to illustrate the problem

http://cdpn.io/muiKa

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your best bet is to replace the transform scaling with good old fashioned em scaling.  Chris Coyer has a awesome article with examples: http://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/

Comment: ...Actually my problem is the content of my div can be text, video, image, svg, ect, and can contain animation or not...