# "-webkit-box-reflect" and "-webkit-transform: scale3d(...)" cause blur on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, scale, blur, css-transforms

I'm experiencing some troubles with Chrome in a project when I try to associate these two webkit properties -webkit-box-reflect and -webkit-transform: scale3d.
When associated and applied on an element, if you try to set a scale between 0 and 1, the div will appear blurred.

I found an other request for that issue on Stackoverflow but no real answer was given to solve the problem. 
[CSS3 Scale combined with reflect makes blurred elements on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373325/css3-scale-combined-with-reflect-makes-blurred-elements-on-chrome)

Considering my element can contain any kind of content (text, image, video, css animations,...), is there an other way to associate reflect and scale on chrome?
The given example on the other post was perfect and I invite you to review it at this link: http://codepen.io/lchenneberg/pen/muiKa

Comment: `box-reflect` is not supported any more AFAIK. No other browser supports it.

Comment: After some research it seems to be supported on these two main browsers:  Safari(6, 7) and Chrome(32, 34)

Comment: In any case, I think the problem is related to bitmap rendering. I had visibly better results when giving .74 to the scale3d. Can you try different values and check if that's the case with you as well? My best guess is that .75 seems to hit a sweet spot that the browser can't render properly at that size.

Comment: I'm using box reflect and scale in a div that fit its container (window object). So when the user resize the window, my div should fit its this container if container surface < element surface. In other words, the scale is calculated from window container size and its nested element size and the scale value could be any value from 0 to 1. The same code works well on Safari and Mobile Safari.